# How do I make this function work for a single time for my html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

```
$(document).ready(function() {    // show popup when you click on the link

   $('.show-popup').hover(function(event){

      event.preventDefault(); // disable normal link function so that it doesn't refresh the page

      var docHeight = $(document).height(); //grab the height of the page

      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); //grab the px value from the top of the page to where >you're scrolling
      var selectedPopup = $(this).data('showpopup'); //get the corresponding popup to show

      $('.overlay-bg').show().css({ 'height' : docHeight }); //display your popup background and set >height to the page height
      $('.popup' + selectedPopup).show().css({ 'top': scrollTop + 20 + 'px' }); //show the appropriate popup >and set the content 20px from the window top

   }   

});
```

Comment: Single time means what exactly? Once per page view, once per week, once ever? You need to learn about localstorage or cookies or even better, serverside code to remember the state and add the code. If it is once per page, than you just unbind the event.

Comment: unbind the event after its execution completed.

Comment: how about [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method in jquery??

Comment: How exactly do I unbind an event?
I meant once per page view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
 $('.show-popup').hover(function(event){

      event.preventDefault(); // disable normal link function so that it doesn't refresh the page

      var docHeight = $(document).height(); //grab the height of the page

      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); //grab the px value from the top of the page to where >you're scrolling
      var selectedPopup = $(this).data('showpopup'); //get the corresponding popup to show

      $('.overlay-bg').show().css({ 'height' : docHeight }); //display your popup background and set >height to the page height
      $('.popup' + selectedPopup).show().css({ 'top': scrollTop + 20 + 'px' }); //show the appropriate popup >and set the content 20px from the window top

      $('.show-popup').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave'); //unbind the event handler
   }
```

Comment: Thank you Sarath, it was very helpful.
Can you help me with this too?
https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20150113204233AAdUMvB

Comment: The "In spotlight" section?

Comment: oh.. sorry brother thats not a marquee.. its an slider made by css and jquery .. you can view the demo here.. http://bxslider.com/examples/image-slideshow-captions             .. more sliders are available in market..FREE

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {    // show popup when you click on the link

   $('.show-popup').hover(function(event){

      event.preventDefault(); // disable normal link function so that it doesn't refresh the page

      var docHeight = $(document).height(); //grab the height of the page

      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); //grab the px value from the top of the page to where >you're scrolling
      var selectedPopup = $(this).data('showpopup'); //get the corresponding popup to show

      $('.overlay-bg').show().css({ 'height' : docHeight }); //display your popup background and set >height to the page height
      $('.popup' + selectedPopup).show().css({ 'top': scrollTop + 20 + 'px' }); //show the appropriate popup >and set the content 20px from the window top
      $(this).removeClass("show-popup");

   }   

});
```

Comment: Thank you SimarjeetSingh.
Can you answer this too?
https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20150113204233AAdUMvB